# Buscar tabla SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos con una cantidad enorme de tablas y vistas. El programa que llama a esa base de datos peta y me da un error cuando intenta llamar a una tabla determinada. ¿Hay alguna opción de buscar dicha tabla? Rollo buscador o algo así?

Comment: cual es el error que aparece?

Comment: Errors occured in call ({call dbo.sp_ING_LoginExt_Jubilacion(?,?,?,?)}): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a int

Comment: Lo mismo iba a preguntar, precisamente porque el error podía no tener que ver con que la tabla existiese o no. Y por lo que se ve, no tenía que ver... Tendrías que compartir dicho procedimiento, y la estructura de la tabla que arroja el error para ayudarte.

Comment: Si no digo que la tabla exista o no, es que como no tengo ni idea de qué error es, iba a empezar investigando por la tabla a ver si encontraba algo. Voy a ver en los enlaces que habéis pasado. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si lo que buscas es mostrar datos de tablas y vistas la siguiente consulta te puede dar esa información `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Has probado a usar `SHOW TABLES;`?, Con esta opción podrás consultar las tablas de tu base de datos.

Si no, también puedes usar `SELECT * FROM sys.tables` , tal como viene en la documentación https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-table-definition

Comment: Agregando a la respuesta de @Gatchan00, en este hilo en inglés de este mismo sitio dan varias opciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server

Comment: Vale, voy a probar. Muchas gracias, compañeros

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `SHOW TABLES;` funciona? Me temo que no es una característica estándar. Lo que sí funciona es el `sys.tables`

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tu error tenga alguna relación con el esquema de la tabla y los permisos que tenga el usuario con el que estás intentando usar el objeto.

El esquema por defecto es .dbo, fíjate si la tabla está de ese modo y si el usuario tiene permisos sobre ese objeto.

Adicionalmente, puedes buscar una tabla con cualquiera de las instrucciones siguientes:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

select * 
from sys.tables


select * 
from sysobjects
where xtype = 'U'
```

Comment: select * from sysobjects para las tablas, si quieres buscar columnas select * from syscolumns y tambien puedes hacer un join entre las dos.

Comment: Existe una diferencia, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` te mostrará también los `VIEW`, `sys.tables` únicamente las tablas definidas o creadas por el usuario.

Answer (score -1):

Para las tablas:

```
select * from sysobjects
```

Si quieres buscar columnas

```
select * from syscolumns
```

Y también puedes hacer un `join` entre las dos.

Si quieres ver la estructura selecciona la tabla y le das <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, en caso de que no exista te enviará un mensaje.

Comment: `systables` existía para SQL Server 2000, en versiones superiores se deberá usar el catálogo de metadatos `sys.tables`

Comment: perdón puedes añadir la referencia donde fundamentas tu comentario, muchas gracias.

Comment: yo creo que si no tienen referencia, no es correcto que coloquen un -1 y menos si aun esta en el motor de SQL y funciona correctamente, de hecho las personas que ya tienen rato en esto yo creo que nunca cambiaran de sysobjects, syscolumns, systypes, etc

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017